# QueryVirtualMemoryInformation

Tags: c, window

I am using QueryVirtualMemoryInformation, but it always fails with a return value of 0. GetLastError() returns 24, and I cannot understand why it fails. My system is Windows 11.

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 32440);
WIN32_MEMORY_REGION_INFORMATION  win32_memory_region_information = { 0 };
PVOID pAddress = 0;
ULONG_PTR uLength = 0;

BOOL ret = QueryVirtualMemoryInformation(hProcess, 0x6d0000, MemoryRegionInfo,
    &win32_memory_region_information, sizeof(WIN32_MEMORY_REGION_INFORMATION), &uLength);
if (!ret)
{
    printf(" %d\n", GetLastError());
}
```

I would like to know the cause of the error and how to resolve it. The process information used in the code above is correct.

Comment: where did you get `0x6d0000` from? while not impossible, it is certainly unusual for a virtual memory address to be that low. Also, make sure `OpenProcess` doesn't return `NULL`

Comment: The process handle can be obtained correctly, and the address is the starting address of the main module of the process. There is no problem with that. Moreover, I have tested it multiple times and made repeated modifications, but still failed, which is why I am seeking help from this website.